# Region of Interest Extraction using DLib

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, dlib

I am working on a image processing project. I need to extract a region of interest from one varible (`cv_image <bgr_pixel>`) to another variable (`cv_image <bgr_pixel>`) with a `dlib::rectangle varible`

In OpenCV, its like:

```
Mat mainImage=cv::imread(location,0);
Mat roi = mainImage(cv::Rect(0,0,100,100))
```

Is there any similar methods in Dlib??

Comment: dlib's rectangle differs from opencv's Rect. if you got a cv::Rect r, it's         dlib::rectangle rec(r.x, r.y, r.x+r.width, r.y+r.height);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`dlib::extract_image_chips()`](http://dlib.net/dlib/image_transforms/interpolation_abstract.h.html#extract_image_chips).  It allows you to specify where the chip comes from in a variety of ways, but you can also simply do `extract_image_chips(in_img, some_rectangle, out_img)`.  However, `out_img` can't be a `cv_image`.  It has to be something like `dlib::array2d` or `dlib::matrix`.  More generally, if you really just want to copy between OpenCV objects then you don't need dlib.

Comment: Why call it a chip? Took some time to find this, I thought sub_image sounded right.

Comment: @lahjaton_j That's just what people call it.

Comment: It's probably just that English is not my first language, but chip brings these into mind: https://www.google.fi/search?q=image+chip